# Why does Xcode not warn this code is unreachable?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

The following code does get marked unreachable:

[image]

However, if I simply change it to the following, then the warning disappears. Why?

[image]

Comment: please check the answer clarifies your query

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a Xcode issue in Clang alpha.deadcode.UnreachableCode Alpha check https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/alpha_checks.html

Update >>

I checked in xcode 8 the issue is not present

[image]

Comment: According to your findings, it is not an Xcode (but a LLVM?) issue.

Comment: @shallowThought seems like issue in Clang

Comment: That's what I thought (Clang is the LLVM's frontend).